# Been Banned From USA for a year for visiting "too soon"?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I was stopped by the american immigration in Atlanta, long-story short they said "you can't return for a year" because I went to go see my girlfriend in the summer and in two months (november) I went to go and see her again for winter (3-5 months). On my connection in Atlanta Homeland security questioned me further because I had a one-way ticket and had already seen my girlfriend in summer and found it suspicious, went through my phone/messaging apps to see my chats with her etc. They stamped me till May 19 but after that I can't return for a year. I wanted to know if there was any way for me to really know if I am banned for a year or if there's some way to fight this?

Comment: Why?  Immigration recognized that you may be visiting your GF with a purpose of potentially starting a family and as they say there is a visa for that.  Having said that this question is better for our sister site Expatriates.SE but even then it's likely to be put on hold even there since it feels more like a rant.

Comment: sorry I've been up for a while feeling a terrible amount of anxiety over this. I guess I never got around to really asking for any help and more or less just went on a rant. I wanted to know if there was any way for me to really know if I am banned for a year or if there's some way to fight this? They found no proof of me wanting to start a family and I only had the one way because my father tried making travelling easier for me by buying my ticket there and I would get the return ticket while I'm in the US. I've had my b2 visa for years and have never committed visa fraud or any crime.

Comment: Expatriates.SE would be a more appropriate place to look for help?

Comment: I don't really see a question here. With a tourist visa (or the visa waiver program), you are expected to be visiting the US temporarily, not living in the country. Frequent extended visits and one-way tickets lead to suspicion that you'll be living in the United States, as most genuine tourist visitors have some ties to their home and so will return there soon enough. Ultimately, they did choose to let you in for another six months, which is great. The broad guideline is that you should spend at least as much time out of the US as you do in it; you've already visited for months and months.

Comment: @crazedpanda expats is more appropriate for longer-term stays, travel for shorter ones. More importantly, please edit the question to reflect the actual question you want to be answered.

Comment: Expatriates.SE would likely be the appropriate place for questions about moving to the US for extended periods of time, which is what you're effectively doing by spending so much time in the country.

Comment: If the CBP agent told you that you would not be allowed in again for one year, then they would have noted that in your record and so yes you will be banned for one year.

Comment: First, try to calm down a bit, and after that try to remember exactly what was said to you and by whom, and most importantly, the exact words that were used. It's very unlikely you would have been told that you were banned for a year, and then allowed in for another six months. If you were actually banned for a year, you would have been put on the next flight to anywhere. I have to mark this as "unclear" for the time being, as I don't believe the post comes close enough to describing what actually took place at the port of entry.

Comment: Well while I was in Atlanta I was talking to a customs officer who found it suspicious that I was staying for a couple of months without a return ticket and explained that I do intend to go back to my country (the cayman islands). He asked another officer to escort me deeper into the airport to homeland security where they asked me more questions like why I didn't want to spend christmas with my family etc which I said I had grown a little distant with my mother (because of my relationship) and ultimately chose to spend christmas with my girlfriend. He took my phone and looked through it but

Comment: It died and he couldn't look through it anymore so he went through my Facebook wall and looked at our relationship. He said that I cannot enter for a year but i don't recall his name, I was really scared and it was my first time being flagged down and I just wanted to comply so I can see my girlfriend again.

Comment: @crazedpanda As I said: There is a different visa for that.

Comment: @Karlson - What visa is available for "Visiting a girlfriend" other than B2?  A V or K-3 are applicable only if they are already married, a K-1 is if they intend to get married while the OP visits (which doesn't really seem to be case presently).  The OPs issue seems to be proving he is only visiting, not planning to marry and stay.

Comment: In short, you are **damn lucky** that they did not refuse you entry and blacklist you for immigration fraud. Do **not** try to fight the year ban by travelling to the US earlier

Comment: There is no such "one-year ban". If they removed you, you would have a 5-year ban. If they didn't remove you, you don't have a ban. However, just because you don't have a ban doesn't mean they will let you in.